# DeadLock in directShow, mutlti video resizing

Tags: c++, video, directshow

1，I'd like to show 9 videos at same time.
2，I have a main thread which create all the windows and handle the WM_* message, also in charge of: A), init vmrvideorender9, MediaControl B), connect filter C), stop and release the MediaControl. and other things.
3，For every video, there is also a render thread which is for sample delivering.

Now, I have many deadlock, they hang at different place and CPU is very high. 
The deadlock most happens when resizing the windows.
for example: when I call the following function, sometimes it can consume 40 seconds and sometimes it just hang inside the function.

```
Void GetVMR9VideoRender()
{

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_IBaseFilter, (LPVOID *)&pRender.p);
    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    CComPtr <IVMRFilterConfig9> pConfig;

    hr =pRender->QueryInterface(IID_IVMRFilterConfig9, (void**)&pConfig);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return NULL;

    pConfig->SetRenderingMode(VMRMode_Windowless);
    pConfig->SetNumberOfStreams(1);

    CComPtr<IVMRWindowlessControl9> lpDefWC;
    hr = pRender->QueryInterface(IID_IVMRWindowlessControl9, (LPVOID*)&lpDefWC.p);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    m_lpDefWC = (IVMRWindowlessControl*)lpDefWC.p ;

    CComPtr<IVMRAspectRatioControl9> lpARC; 
    hr = pRender->QueryInterface(IID_IVMRWindowlessControl9, (LPVOID*)&lpARC.p);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    m_lpARC = (IVMRAspectRatioControl*)lpARC.p ;

    return pRender;
}
```

Comment: Code snippet is irrelevant to deadlock. Once it locks dead you need to break in with debugger and inspect stacks to identify where the deadlock takes place exactly.

Comment: What source filters do you use? Do you add your own custom filters to the filtergraph?

Comment: I have two filters in the filtergraph, The source filter is defined by myself and inherit from CBaseFilter.  and another one is the render filter.                                                   And I print the time, the most consume time sentence is SetRenderingMode function.